# Emacs doesn't kill-yank anymore after Xubuntu upgrade to 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, emacs

I just upgraded Xubuntu on my laptop from 13.10 to 14.04. Emacs' version is 24.3.1. Everything is working fine except the kill-yank system (copy-paste).

To investigate this, I open emacs in my home ("cd; emacs -nw"), create a file ("C-x C-f test.txt"), write a few dummy lines and kill-yank one of them ("C-space C-n Esc-w"). But when I enter the last command ("Esc-w"), the mini-buffer displays the following message:

```
The mark is not set now, so there is no region
```

I have no idea what is going on and how to fix this. Any advice?

Here are a few more remarks that can help find the cause of the problem:

- when I open emacs with a window (that is, without option "-nw"), kill-yank still doesn't work with the keyboard shortcuts (as above), but it does work with the mouse
- my emacs profile ("~/.emacs") is [here](https://github.com/timflutre/perso/blob/master/emacs) didn't change with the upgrade and doesn't have anything related to kill-yank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior was due to IBus, as explained [here](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/10978/emacs-key-binding-ctrlspace-not-working-on-fedora-16-gnome-or-xfce/?answer=14990#post-id-14990). So I opened a terminal, executed the command `ibus-setup` and there I changed Ctrl into Alt. I hope it won't break anything, but at least `C-<SPC>` now sets the mark in Emacs.